# Ceiling fan light flickers when fan is used

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, led, dimmer-switch

I have a double-gang box with a [Leviton dimmer switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RrAV.jpg), a [Lutron fan switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htlVs.png), and ran 14/3 to a [Hunter 53408 ceiling fan](https://www.hunterfan.com/products/ceiling-fans-lincoln-with-3-led-lights-52-inch-fama84).

I wired everything up and the controls work well, independently; the Leviton dims the T12 3.5W LED bulbs and the Lutron adjusts the fan from low to medium to high.

When both are turned on and I adjust the Lutron speed, the bulbs will sporadically flicker off and on. This does not happen every single time but there's a 50% chance that a flicker occurs when adjusting the fan speed.

Do I have a hardware incompatibility?

---

One guess is that the Lutron is causing some weird fluctuation on the neutral but I'm no expert.

My second guess is that the leads for the fan versus light is not adequately separated inside the fan housing.

---

Per request, below is a wiring diagram. I made it from memory so if something looks off then please request clarity.

[image]

---

Update 1:

Adjusting the ceiling fan speed will sometimes make the ceiling light stay on at full brightness after flickering. Turning the Lutron on or off also affects the behavior of the light.

The flicker will also affect a dimmer+light on the same circuit in an adjacent hallway. Same Leviton dimmer but this has a Great Value bulb. This light always returns to normal after a flicker.

---

Update 2:

Leaving the Lutron on high and using the pull strings on the fan causes zero issues for the bulbs.

There is another light on the same circuit which is not dimmable and it experiences zero flicker.

Comment: Does it happen when the lights are on and then turn on the fan(fan off)?

Comment: @crip659 Hmm, I did not test that combination. I'll test it when I get home using all fan speeds.

Comment: Yep. According to your diagram the power supply (hot) for the light kit passes through multiple switches. I don't see the three- and four-wire cables I'd expect with a *-way setup.

Comment: @isherwood I'll need a moment to re-assess my diagram. Do note that there are two power feeds from the same circuit; one close and one far. I avoided running 12/3 as travelers for the middle 4-way.

Comment: @isherwood My diagram is accurate from everything I remember. Is there a specific problem you see with the wiring?

Comment: I'm going to let some of our more experienced users weigh in. This strikes me as an odd situation, but maybe that's my inexperience showing.

Comment: @isherwood Well, I appreciate the requests for clarity. I was hoping to avoid making the diagram but I'm glad I did. My fear now is that I have to find some non-existent compatibility matrix between the fan, bulbs, dimmer switch, and fan switch =/

Comment: take a peek at the dimmer's bulb compatibility chart, flickering is a common issue with dimmers and LEDs. The fan's bundled bulbs may not be correct for the dimmer: https://www.leviton.com/en/docs/Dimmer-Forward-and-Reverse-Application-Note.pdf

Comment: @Yorik The dimmer dims the bulbs without issue though.

Comment: I meant to also say that I had a specific instance with LED bulbs in a ceiling fixture and a dimmer where there would be flickering at certain dimmer settings with 3 bulbs but no flicker if I removed one bulb from the fixture. Beyond my pay grade, but it may be related to loading?

Comment: The LEDs might not like the power changes for the changing fan speeds.

Comment: @crip659 Ceiling fan on/off does affect the lights. Please see my update.

Comment: Imagine that the LEDs are sensitive to minor power changes in the circuit.  Does the flicker stop after a bit or does it keep happening?  Change the speed and see a couple of flickers or change the speed and flicking keeps happening for a long time.

Comment: @crip659 it's a single flicker per speed or on/off change and it will result in either full brightness or back to the dim setting.

Comment: Think all types of lights are affected by power changes, most are too little to tell most times, maybe a very slight dimming.  LEDs just show it more.  Some makes might be less sensitive, but it could get expensive finding the right one.

Comment: @crip659 I'm starting to think that the dimmer is not liking the voltage fluctuations so it's sending erratic signals to the bulbs.

Comment: What is the extra red line & purple square coming off the dimmer in your diagram?

Comment: @FreeMan That's the fan controller. It has no terminal screws for wires but rather excess leads. The red+white wire is used for 3-way switching. It's capped off because I am using single-pole. If you can view Home Depot then see 5a of https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/29/299ad5aa-497e-41d4-a0e9-a78c81edc4de.pdf

Comment: Gotcha. Was thinking that may be it, but clarity is important.

Comment: @FreeMan No worries, glad to see this post is still getting some sort of traction =)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the diagram, I see two problems. I don't know whether or not they would cause these exact symptoms, but they are code violations and not good. Fix them and the rest of the problem *may* go away.

##### 2-wire cable between 3-way and 4-way switches

With a traditional (not "smart") setup, you **must** have 3 wires between any set of 3-way and 4-way switches. Two of the wires are *travelers*, each carrying power some of the time depending on which switches are up vs. down. In this diagram, those are the black and white wires.

**Ground is irrelevant** and is connected here properly, but has nothing to do with this issue. Ground is not neutral. Ground is not counted as one of the wires in branch circuit "2 wire" or "3 wire" or "4 wire" cables, because you always need it and it doesn't usually carry current except under fault conditions. (Some smart switches can use it, but that is a special case.)

The third wire, **which is not present here**, can be:

- Neutral
- Hot
- Switched Hot

depending on the configuration.

Currents are supposed to be equal/opposite. That cancels out certain issues that can cause heating in wires, among other things. I don't quite understand the physics of it, but this is a real issue and required in code. Basically any time wires are outside a box they need to match up in this way.

Which leads to the second problem:

##### Unbalanced Neutrals

Neutral is always supposed to have the same current (but opposite) as the matching hot or switched hot wire. From the fan/light switch box ("problematic switches") to the fan/light, the switched hots and neutral are 100% balanced.

However, from the fan/light switch box down to where everything merges together (purple junction near "Power (one circuit)"), the neutral wire is carrying the light and fan power but the hot wire is only carrying the fan power.

There is no *easy* solution. The proper solution requires running /3 cable. And not just replacing the /2 that is there with /3, but also reconfiguring so that instead of:

- Panel -> left 3-way -> 4-way -> right 3-way -> light

it is:

- Panel -> right 3-way -> 4-way -> left 3-way -> light

The more *practical* solution is likely to be:

- Replace the dimmer with a "smart" dimmer that can use either wireless (battery powered but look like regular switches) remotes or wired remotes that only need 2 wires (including not just another 3-way but also the 4-way in the middle).

Comment: I just wanted to take a moment and say thank you for the very informative answer. I completely overlooked the rule to balance neutrals. Realistically, is it a problem if the hot travelers are only carrying the current for 3 LED bulbs? Regardless, couldn't I remedy the situation if I replaced the 14/2 travelers with 14/2/2? This would allow me to remove power from the right box so that all switched power travels back to the left box; I think...

Comment: Is it that much of real problem with 3 LED bulbs, probably less than 1/2 amp? Probably not. But it is a code violation and the issue is future changes that make use of existing stuff and then a little problem can become a BIG problem. Would 14/2/2 do it? Probably, but would have to think about the wiring quite a bit...

Comment: I think the 14/2/2 would allow me to use a switched hot for the lights starting from the left and there would be a live hot **and** neutral passed through the 4-way box till it's needed all the way at the fan switch. This *should* keep the loads balanced regardless of which switch is on or off.

Answer (score -1):

I know this thread is old but the Lutron dimmer switch you are using is not supposed to be used with led bulbs per manufacturer. It says compatible with incandescent and halogen bulb types.

Comment: It's a good thing I'm using a Leviton switch for the lights and a Lutron for the ceiling fan...

Comment: It's also not a "thread" but a question. Please take the [tour] to see how things work a bit differently here.